# NoSuchMethodException thrown while deploying Struts 2 app to tomcat 7

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat7

Getting the below exception when this web service gets deployed into tomcat 7.

> May 25, 2021 7:20:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
> INFO: Marking servlet com_xxx_mm_mf_mst_ws_actions_MOCSkuLookUpAction as unavailable
> May 25, 2021 7:20:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
> SEVERE: Servlet /mst threw load() exception
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.ws.actions.MOCSkuLookUpAction.()
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:140)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Blockquote

This is the servlet defined in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>com_xxx_mm_mf_mst_ws_actions_MOCSkuLookUpAction</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.ws.actions.MOCSkuLookUpAction</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and these are the java classes defined for the WS.
MOCSkuLookUpAction.java and also I have the constructors in the implementation class, stub and in the skeleton classes.

```
public interface MOCSkuLookUpAction extends java.rmi.Remote {
    public com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.to.TicketDispTO[] loadTicketList(int skuNbr, java.lang.String strNbr, com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.to.ClientTO user) throws java.rmi.RemoteException, com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.ws.exceptions.MOCApplicationException;
    public com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.to.UpcTO getSkuInfo(int skuNbr, java.lang.String strNbr, com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.to.ClientTO user) throws java.rmi.RemoteException, com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.ws.exceptions.MOCApplicationException;
    public java.lang.Object[] getReasonCodes(int actionTyp) throws java.rmi.RemoteException, com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.ws.exceptions.MOCApplicationException;
    public com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.to.TicketDispTO[] createTicket(int skuNbr, java.lang.String strNbr, com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.to.ClientTO user, java.lang.String actionType, int reasonCode) throws java.rmi.RemoteException, com.xxx.mm.mf.mst.ws.exceptions.MOCApplicationException;
}
```

Any idea why this exception is happening? I couldn't find anything related to this in the logs exception the exception shown above.

Comment: Q: did you happen to define a constructor in your implementation class?

Comment: package paths are different in xml file and error stack trace for class MOCSkuLookUpAction

Comment: I have the constructors in the implementation class, stub and in the skeleton classes. I obfuscated the path in the xml but not in the exception trace.